# how to get the client id of all the textbox in a row inside the grid on using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> i have a editable Gridview(containing 7 editable fields/textbox in
>   each row).on button(update) click i want to find the id of the all the textbox so that i can check if the textbox is empty or not.
>   for that i am doing this as the textbox of the client id in chrome **GridSubMeter_ctl10_txtMeterIdnbut** 
>   but the client id is getting dynamically made in different browsers(different in firefox,opera).

```
var v = val.id.split('_')[2];
           var merter = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' +  v +'txtMeterIdn_' ).value.trim();
           var Billper = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + 'txBillPer_' ).value.trim()
           var Endkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + 'txEndKwh_' ).value.trim();
           var startkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + 'txStartKwh_').value.trim();
           var ReadEndDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' +  v+'txReadEndDate_' ).value.trim();
           var ReadStartDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v+'txReadStartDate_' ).value.trim();
           var CTFACT = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v+ 'txCTFact_' ).value.trim();
```

**GEIDVIEW** 
[image: GRID]

**JS FUNCTION**

```
   function fnCheck(val) {
               var success = true;
               var text1 = val.value;
               var v = val.id.split('_')[2];
               var merter = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' +  v +'txtMeterIdn_' ).value.trim();
               var Billper = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + 'txBillPer_' ).value.trim()
               var Endkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + 'txEndKwh_' ).value.trim();
               var startkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + 'txStartKwh_').value.trim();
               var ReadEndDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' +  v+'txReadEndDate_' ).value.trim();
               var ReadStartDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v+'txReadStartDate_' ).value.trim();
               var CTFACT = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v+ 'txCTFact_' ).value.trim();

               var btn = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v+'btn_Update_' );
               debugger;
                           if (merter != '') {
                           }
                           else {
                               alert("Meter Identifier is Required Field");
                               success = false;
                           }
               if (Billper != '') {
               }
               else {
                   alert("Bill Period is Required Field");
                   success = false;
               }
               if (Endkwh != '') {
               }
               else {
                   alert("EndKwh is Required Field");
                   success = false;
               }
               if (startkwh != '') {
               }
               else {
                   alert("StartKwh is Required Field");
                   success = false;
               }
               if (ReadEndDate != '') {
               }
               else {
                   alert("Read EndDate is Required Field");
                   success = false;
               }
               if (ReadStartDate != '') {
               }
               else {
                   alert("Read StartDate is Required Field");
                   success = false;
               }
                           if (CTFACT != '') {
                           }
                           else {
                               alert("CT Factor is Required Field");
                               success = false;
                           }
```

**ASPX Button code**

```
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" OnClientClick="return fnCheck(this);" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add class names that are static so you always have the ability to query the context even if the id is dynamically input. If for example each text field has the class `textBox` you could do;

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("textBoxes");
```

Then iterate through the nodelist passed back;

```
for(var x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++){

console.log(boxes[0].id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `-`, `/` or any other character that is not alphanumeric when naming your IDs.

I suggest using camel case when naming your IDs and train case when naming your classes. Use IDs for javascript, classes for style (CSS) related codes.

By sticking with this convention, your IDs won't be named differently across browsers.